# jQuery countdown resets itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I took this code from [this link](https://shadowcores.twifysoft.net/#timeToServerSave) (this is also example how that script should work), my markup looks like this **`<td id="timeToServerSave">`** and below are my JS & Bootstrap libraries.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?PHP echo $layout_name; ?>/js/bs-sc.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?PHP echo $layout_name; ?>/js/application.js"></script>
<script>var secondsToServerSave</script>
```

Counter is almost working like I wanted it to work, but everytime I refresh page, it restarts to 23h 59m 59s and going down (like it's supposed to).

Below you can also find jQuery code I mentionted in first words.

```
function updateServerSaveTimer()
{
    secondsToServerSave -= 1;
    if(secondsToServerSave < 0) {
        secondsToServerSave = 86400;
    }

    var hours = Math.floor(secondsToServerSave / 3600);
    var str;
    if (hours != 1) {
        str = hours + " hours, ";
    } else {
        str = "1 hour, ";
    }
    str += Math.floor((secondsToServerSave % 3600) / 60) + " min and " + (secondsToServerSave % 60) + " sec.";
    $('#timeToServerSave').html(str);
}

    setInterval('updateServerSaveTimer()', 1000);
});
```

I'm not very familiar with jQuery and JS, I tried everything I could, and I can't still solve this problem.

Comment: Every time you restart the script is going to start over from the beginning.

Comment: If you want the countdown to be persistent between page loads, you'll need to use cookies or a server-side script.

Comment: Patrick is right. Your gonna wanna interact via ajax or wanna add a cookie to check the countdown.

Comment: any tips @jamadri Patric ?

Comment: This question looks about like the same as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235816/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-with-jquery

Comment: not at all @jamadri he asked about separating each counter, i have one counter, and i need it to run even if no one is on my website, so it has to run server side.

Comment: @RafalOlszewski - "run server side" - you just totally confused the question with that comment as this is JavaScript which is not typically server side.
Please also update your question with a fully functional example which may help clarify your intent here.  You might for example format the code as a snippet so it can run here.

Comment: So you want everyone on your site to access this same counter and said counter resides on the server side?  IF so please include in your tags which server side language AND what you tried there, editing your question to reflect a clearly asked question.